# There was no Home CMS page configured or found magento 2.1.7

Tags: cms, magento-2.1.7, home-page

I've the error.

There was no Home CMS page configured or found.

On the magento website homepage, I've tried to clean the cache, reindex, run the command **setup:upgrade** but still got the error.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the page that you choose for the home page have the store view included in the option PAGE IN WEBSITE.

Content > Pages> Home(or the name of your home page) > Edit > Page in website

Comment: Your answer inspired me, The solution was changing the default store of the website to be my current default demo.

Comment: worked Thanks ..!

Answer (score 2):

```
Store > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page
```

Try to clear your Magento Cache. And, make sure that this config is for your current storefront. Please, check the config for current store view.

Also, check that assigned CMS Home Page Store view setting.

Comment: I've checked, all correct but still the error

Answer (score 0):

Here what works with me on Magento 2.3.1

Go to

```
Store > All stores
```

Then choose your website and change `Default Store` to the default demo that you have chosen in:

```
Store > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page
```

Answer (score 0):

We had bilingual hiring done through Envato. Now we get the message "There was no Home CMS page configured or found." when we switch to Rubix 2 in System and Content. We pay the customization, because we have chosen the template because of the good and beautiful category display.